# Sorting huge file for Python

Tags: python, bash, sorting, python-3.7

I implemented a [Binary Search Algorithm](https://github.com/MrTomRod/BinaryFileSearch) for Python3. The problem is that it requires files to be sorted according to Pythons string comparison logic. Bash `sort` doesn't do that. Example:

```
aa      first
aaA     second
aaa     third
```

This file is sorted correctly according to Python3 because `'aa' < 'aaA' < 'aaa'`

If I sort it using bash (`sort --key=1 --field-separator=$'\t' file.txt`), I get:

```
aaA     second
aaa     third
aa      first
```

Is there an **efficient** way to sort huge files 'correctly' for Python?

Would it be easier to teach my algorithm the bash string comparison method?

Comment: I'm not clear which way of sorting you want and in which tool? (python or bash)

Comment: There are two options, both would be acceptable to me: 1) sort differently using bash so that python has no problem; 2) sort using bash's algorithm but teach python bash's string comparison logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sort` uses your `locale`'s rules for sorting. Apparently, you want "C"-style sorting.

So change your locale, just for your sort command:

```
LC_ALL=C sort $your_file
```

Also, you don't need to specify `--key=1` since it's the default.

And `--field-separator=\t` does not set it to a tab-character but to a plain "t". If you need to specify the tab character, you can write `--field-separator=$'\t'`.

Comment: brilliant, thank you, and thanks for the correction. I'm changing my question accordingly to avoid confusion in the future.

Answer (score 2):

The bash ordering depends on your preferences. Your sorting preference can be found with

```
echo "LC_ALL"
```

When I use

```
export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
```

I get your "wrong" ordering.
This can be "fixed" by

```
export LC_ALL=C
```

or

```
# wrong: LC_ALL=C sort --key=1 --field-separator=\t file.txt
```

EDIT:
@mivk answered with some corrections, command should be

```
LC_ALL=C sort --field-separator=$'\t' file.txt
```